# HTTP Post from Windows Forms application C#

Tags: c#, winforms, http-post

I need to write a forms application in C# that sends parameters via HTTP POST to a url, and gets back the response.

I really don't realize where to start this, is it possible at all ?

Thanks in advance, Gal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a start please see

1- HttpWebRequest Class

2- HttpWebResponse Class

3- WebClient Class

in MSDN

Please see  [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/httpwebrequest_response.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

This isn't in C# but you should be able to intepret it.

```
var
  Bytes: Array of Byte;
  Request: HttpWebRequest;
  RequestStream: Stream;
  Response: HttpWebResponse;
  ResponseStream: StreamReader;
begin  
    Bytes := Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data); //Where data is your data (XML in my case)
    Request := WebRequest.CreateDefault(Uri.Create(URL)) as HttpWebRequest;
    Request.Method := 'POST';
    Request.ContentLength := Length(Bytes);
    Request.ContentType := 'application/xml'; //Set accordingly

    RequestStream := Request.GetRequestStream;
    RequestStream.Write(Bytes, 0, Length(Bytes));
    RequestStream.Close;

    Response := Request.GetResponse as HttpWebResponse;
    ResponseStream := StreamReader.Create(Response.GetResponseStream, Encoding.ASCII);
    Result := ResponseStream.ReadToEnd;
    ResponseStream.Close;
```

If you need clarification, let me know.

Comment: Seems like Delphi

Comment: @I'mBlueDaBaDee That it is.