# passing Parameters(such as form feeds) to Website from WinForm(C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, httpwebrequest

I'm on my journey of learning C#. I was trying to create an app to get exam results by asking the user to enter his roll number.

I know I have to use `httpwebrequest` or something sounding similar.

Here is the source page snippet of the result.php page

```
<form action="resultstatus.php" method="post" name="myform" id="myform">
   <p align="center">
      <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">
      <span class="style6">Please enter your Application Number or Registration Number </span>
      <input type="text" name="regno" size="12" maxlength="10" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onenter = "submit" onclick="submit" />
```

How can I pass this roll no to the server, so that I can have an HTML page to work upon?

How can this be done for a username, password, etc?

this is what i hv done till now and it produces no result :

```
Byte[] Bytes;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://xvc.com/result.php");
Stream RequestStream;
HttpWebResponse Response;

Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("006453");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = Bytes.Length;
request.ContentType  = "text/Html"; //Set accordingly

RequestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
RequestStream.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
RequestStream.Close();

Response = ( HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse(); 
StreamReader ResponseStream = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
```

string Result = ResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
    ResponseStream.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(Result);

Comment: It feels like you have two questions intertwined together.  What does Winforms and logging into a PHP site have to do with getting exam results based off of a roll number?  Are you trying to use a Winforms app to connect to a web page, enter information, and get back the results?

Comment: @BiggsTRC : Exactly, i am trying to make the app that will pass on the roll no., obtain resultstatus.php and then show only the result,, plus i was not able to figure out what to call it exactly so i said : logging to website, any advice on that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have to create a HTTP POST to `resultstatus.php` and provide it with the roll no (`regno`).

You'll probably want to see [this almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302173/http-post-from-windows-forms-application-c) and in particular [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302173/http-post-from-windows-forms-application-c).

Comment: Oh got it finally.. Thanks for providing the links .:)

Comment: Sorry - POST sends the data in the message body, rather than the header which is what GET uses.

Comment: So, if the method is a GET then i should add the param name and value as a header rather than in the RequestStream??

Comment: That's correct, a GET can only send values via the header and not the request body, that's one of their fundamental differences.