# C# post username/password to the login page using windows application

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, http-post

i have login page with 2 textbox and 1 button

```
<input name="txtUserName" type="text" value="666" id="txtUserName" class="textbox">
```

and

```
<input name="txtPassword" type="password" id="txtPassword" class="textbox">
```

and button is like this

```
<input type="submit" name="LoginButton" value="Login To WebSite" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;LoginButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;Login1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="LoginButton" class="button" style="font-family:tahoma;font-size:10px;">
```

> i have not source code of web page and only thing that i want to send
>   my user name andd password and  receive is "login is OK or login is
>   FAIL"

when user enter user name and password and click "Login To WebSite" button ,if user/pass correct user login to page http://example.com/Default.aspx  that show user panel and if login fail system show login.aspx again
now i design windows application that have 2 textbox and one button
i want when i click button textbox1 and textbox2 text send to web site as login information and if this data is correct show me message that login is successful and else show me error

Comment: Are you using the default forms authentication? Have you tried the asp:login control? If you use this control, the redirect will be as simple as setting the destinationpageurl property or redirecting using the logged in event. [Read](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/login-control-in-Asp-Net-3-5/) for more information.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's got it working in ASP.Net but now is trying to do the same with a Windows app.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal:what is your meaning of "why not here"???web site is based asp.net and i cant access source code..i wnat to access my page using windows application

Comment: only man that find out my question is Lesin3r.....but asp.net page is not my work and i have not access to source code..do you under stand??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press "Login To Website" button in ASP.Net it calls the javascript WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions function.

According to [this MSDN Magazine's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163736.aspx), this function performs a POST operation onto the selected page.

To do that in a Windows application you can use the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) (see the sample code at the bottom of the MSDN page) or a combination of [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx).

How to use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse [is described in this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6554/How-to-use-HttpWebRequest-and-HttpWebResponse-in-N).

[Note that I based my answer on this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302173/http-post-from-windows-forms-application-c-sharp).

Comment: do you have any complete example?? i want to send user name and password.how can i do it??

Comment: I don't have a complete example, but it should be pretty easy to setup. On the "OnClick" handler of your button, grab the text from the username textbox and password textbox, form a request with an HttpRequest, post it to the server URL, and wait for the HttpResponse to arrive. If you get a response code of 401 then it's a fail, if it's 200 then it's a success.

Comment: my problem is how to grab text form text box or generally  from controls

Comment: In Windows Forms when you add controls in the designer you can retrieve them by name. So give a name to your textboxes and when you want to retrieve the text use the TextBox.Text property (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx)